# Tengo una pagina PHP con link con acceso en mi PC si la abre pero en otra maquina en RED no abre d echo cuando le da click se abren en la mia

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

tengo un  problema hice una página en php con PhpMyAdmin  conectado  con XamPP
Si abre la página , si muestra  la base de datos  me conecto  en otra maquina y si lo abre  y si hace la búsqueda , lo raro lo tengo en los link que al darle  un link en mi maquina si abre el programas (digamos  Word  o Excel)  pero en la otra máquina al darle un click al enlace  lo abre pero  en mi máquina.Tengo  varios  enlaces y si le doy  en la otra maquina los abre directamente en la mía  que me hacer falta por cambia….   Le pongo un bat , le pongo un exe le pongo otra extensión  (si los abre) pero se va a  mi máquina  y los abre no los abre en la máquina de donde se le da un click

Comment: Podrias ser mas especifico? A que te refieres por "links" y que tiene que ver los programas "word, excel" con lo que dices? Recuerda que si esta en red, se mostrara los archivos de la maquina que inicio el servicio(apache)

Answer (score 0):

Te explico como puedes hacerlo:

1. Debes tener una ip fija para el equipo principal.
2. Necesitas instalar en tu equipo un host como xampp o wampp o laragon.
3. Debes configurar 1 host virtual con un dominio: aplicaciones.delacasa
4. Debes configurar todos los archivos host de los sistemas operativos (todas las pc de tu red) donde quieres acceder a esta web:

```
    192.168.1.120    aplicaciones.delacasa
```

5. en tu web debes desarrollar un lanzador de aplicaciones como la que usa la web de Discord o de Zoom, Este es un link de un ejemplo:
   https://weblogs.asp.net/morteza/How-to-run-a-desktop-application-from-a-web-page
6. a esto se le conoce como IRC Link:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/63606874/4717133
7. Claro que todo dependerá de si la app esta instalada: word, excel power point etc... a esto solo le veo un uso domestico, no profesional.

Comment: Muchas gracias Francisco Núñez voy a seguir las recomendaciones para ver la solución a este inconveniente, feliz día.

Comment: Gracias  , voy a realizar tus pasos ,  mi pagina  esta echa en php  , Si tengo una IP fija  digamos 192.168.100.10 , tengo instalado  el XAMPP , voy a checar ese host virtual ya que si acceso a otra maquina  192.168.100.15 y le doy click a un enlace para ejecutar un bat o exe  SI lo ejecuta pero me lo abre en mi PC 192.168.100.10 , puse por ejemplo  word pero  son programas (ejecutables) de mi empresa  que los quiero tener disponible , saludos

Comment: si es para tu empresa puedes ir un poco mas haya...